# Continous humming kind of sound from speakers after dual boot

Tags: 14.04, dual-boot, sound, windows-8, speakers

I have just dual booted my system (added ubuntu over windows 8.1) and I have heard that there might be few hardware malfunctions after dual booting.
My speakers just work fine in ubuntu (new os) but in windows 8.1 (existing os), they make a continuous sound (the one we get when changing radio stations) for a few seconds (ranging from 5 to 50 seconds approx). This sound is made whenever there is some sound from speakers for the first time.
Is this a hardware problem or hardware malfunction due to dual booting ?
Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

This is very unlikely to be an issue with dual booting at all not sure where you would have heard that one!

If it is working fine under Ubuntu and not under windows I’d suggest you check your drivers on windows or the speakers using a different device.

It sounds like a hardware related issue not a software related issue.